# regular expression to search text

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the text string that is between UBICADO and COMUNA
I am occupying the following regular expression "  `((ubicado) =?).*`  " but I do not know how to arm it so that it takes up "comuna"

"departamento número veintidós del segundo piso, señalan, **ubicado** en calle Victoria Subercaseaux número ciento noventa y uno, **Comuna** de Santiago, Región Metropolitana, y demás derechos en los bienes comunes, en proporción al valor del mismo, entre los cuales se encuentra el terreno, que deslinda: NORTE, calle Valdivia; SUR, propiedad de doña Laura Zegers de"

Comment: do you need to include both `UBICADO` and `COMUNA` as part of the match?

Comment: `(ubicado.*?Comuna)`?

Comment: or put `.*`  in the regex @zzxyz suggested within a pair of parenthesis and get anything between those two words by accessing match group 1.

Comment: `'(?i)(?<=ubicado ).*?(?= comuna)'` - between, but not including, those words using lookarounds. Non-greedy, case-insensitive.

Comment: @Matt.G, oonly what is inside ubicado and comuna, ubicado and comuna not part of the match

Comment: which programming language are you using?

Comment: is a software...  (ubicado.*?Comuna)?  This phrase has served me but includes in the output the words ubicado and comuna

Comment: thanks to all ! I have already solved !